# Google de-indexing our desktop site after we launched a separate mobile site with fewer pages

Tags: seo, mobile, rel-alternate, desktop, mobile-first-index

Recently, we launched separate URL site `m.example.com` for mobile users.  That was a mistake because we don't have corresponding pages on mobile for every page on the desktop version. We have fewer pages on the `m.example.com` website compared to `www.example.com`.

Google started to index our mobile pages.  This causes keywords for desktop to disappear. To recover from this problem we thought to put `rel=alternate` and `rel=canonical` but as I said we don't have all pages on mobile.  Some products are not available for mobile so we don't have these pages for mobile.

I thought to make responsive version, but it would take too much time. What can I do?

Comment: Can you add all the pages to your mobile site?

Comment: No, we can't add all the desktop pages to mobile, because many products are only available for desktop users.

Comment: Why would a product only be available to a desktop user?   Like Windows software?  Even then, I'd think somebody could buy it on mobile to use it on their computer.

Comment: These are some games actually, different for pc and mobile users. but the main thing is: in this situation how to optimize it for SEO.

Comment: Put up the page for the game on the mobile site, but say that you have to be on a PC to play it?

Comment: yes, so I am also thinking for the common pages, just connect these by canonical and alternate, but still wondering what will happen with the rest pages which are not common in both.

Answer (score 2):

The best recommendation that I have is to be as explicit as possible for when you do have a mobile URL and for when you do not. The best method for this is to state this in your sitemap as is indicated in the official Google documentation here: https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls#annotation-in-sitemaps.

Per the Google documentation your sitemap URLs should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<url>
<loc>http://www.example.com/page-1/</loc>
<xhtml:link
rel="alternate"
media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)"
href="http://m.example.com/page-1" />
</url>
</urlset>
```

Answer (score 1):

For pages where you have both desktop and mobile versions of the page:

- On your `example.com` page, put a `canonical` pointing to the `example.com` page and an `alternate` pointing to the `m.example.com` page.
- On your `m.example.com` page, put a `canonical` pointing to the `example.com` page.

For pages where you have only a desktop version:

- On your `example.com` page, put a `canonical` pointing to `example.com` page and do not use an `alternate` tag (because there is no alternate representation).
- Leave your `m.example.com` page nonexistant.

This setup ensures that Google will always index your `example.com` pages as canonical pages and won't get confused and index any `m.example.com` pages, because it will see them as an alternate resource representation.

When a visitor visits your `example.com` page, detect if they are on a mobile device. If they are both on a mobile device and you also have a mobile representation of the page they are viewing, redirect them to the `m.example.com` version of the page.